# How can I enlarge the Mac’s preview window?

Tags: macos, finder

Pressing `space` on a selected file in *Finder* evokes a preview window. Can I enlarge the size of this window *by default* to get a larger preview e.g. of images?

Answer (score 2):

This is answered over [here](https://superuser.com/questions/211750/mac-os-x-how-can-i-adjust-the-default-popup-size-of-quick-look-in-finder), but basically you'll need to edit the "QLPreviewHeight" and "QLPreviewWidth" values in the `Info.plist` file inside the QuickLook plugin that handles images (you'll need select the plugin and choose "Show Package Contents" to get at the plist).

You can see your list of plugins with the command: `qlmanage -m plugins`

If qlmanage shows that "public.images" are handled by the built-in plugin (`/System/Library/QuickLook/Image.qlgenerator`), you shouldn't need to adjust dimensions since the window opens to the image's size by default. However if you do need to make changes, just copy the plugin into your directory (`~/Library/QuickLook`) and then edit it with Apple's XCode (downloadable from the App Store).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to click/drag the corners of the Quick Look window. I at least know you can in OS X El Capitan.

Comment: This works once but the question is about setting a default.